# Channel__lifecycle Database in Hyperledger Fabric 2.3

Tags: database, hyperledger-fabric, channel

I am on CouchDB to view mychannel_lifecycle database of the hyperledger fabric network.
I have 1 chaincode called, mychaincode that runs on mychannel.

This channel_lifecycle database has 5 docs.

1. _id: "namespaces/metadata/mychaincode"
2. _id: namespaces/fields/mychaincode/ValidationInfo
3. namespaces/fields/mychaincode/Sequence
4. namespaces/fields/mychaincode/EndorsementInfo
5. namespaces/fields/mychaincode/Collections

I am showing JSON of doc 5:

```
{
  "_id": "namespaces/fields/mychaincode/Collections",
  "_rev": "1-359fd70b2fa894367f8271c93da0123e",
  "~version": "CgMBBgA=",
  "_attachments": {
    "valueBytes": {
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "revpos": 1,
      "digest": "md5-v/PXRhXnQpiCnsKHFTVXLg==",
      "length": 2,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me understand what this database is saving? how and when were these docs created?
When will these docs be updated or new one will be added?
how and where is digest coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The `_lifecycle` database is an internal database that Fabric uses to track each chaincode definition version deployed to a channel. `_lifecycle` itself is implemented as a system chaincode on each channel, this is why you see it along with the other user chaincodes in the set of channel databases.

The digest is simply a CouchDB artifact when data is stored as a CouchDB binary attachment. Fabric stores any data that is not JSON as a binary attachment in CouchDB.